# Fuzzy Filtering for Non-Exact Values in dplyr?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, fuzzy-search

Does there exist a way to implement a fuzzy filter in dplyr? By "fuzzy filter", I mean something that will match two values even if they aren't exactly the same but are similar, `ie: "racecar == "raceacr`

I'd assume that something with a distance formula could be worked out, though I'm not sure how I'd do that.

Comment: `?agrep` ..... ?

Comment: There are also `%like%` operators in `data.table` and `DescTools`, these operate with a *pattern* similar to `agrep` as suggested

Comment: Ah, for some reason I'd never heard of `agrep` before. Thanks for the help!